# Strange behaviour with getFilter() inside RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am building a small dictioanry app as a side project, screenshot below:

[image]

My `getFilter()` method is working properly and is filtering the results correctly, and when you click on the actual result, a dialog window with information appears. Everything looks fine.

The problem comes when I click on the empty area below the results.
Then I start getting dialog windows for items from the full arraylist `items`, even though they seem to be invisible.
It seems like their `onClick` method gets triggered inside the empty space.

Check screenshot below:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Is this a normal filtering behaviour?

Below is the code for my `Adapter`:

```
    class RecyclerViewAdapter(private var items: ArrayList<Item>, private val listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private var itemsFull = ArrayList(Item)


    inner class ViewHolder (itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        var item: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item)
        val icon: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFavourites)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position: Int = absoluteAdapterPosition
            val currentItem = items[position]
            val item = currentItem.itemName
            val definition = currentItem.itemDefinition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(item,definition,currentItem)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = items[position]
        viewHolder.item.text = currentItem.itemName

        viewHolder.icon.setOnClickListener {
            if (!Constants.favourites.contains(currentItem)) {
                Constants.favourites.add(currentItem)
                viewHolder.icon.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(viewHolder.icon.context, R.anim.shake))
                Toasty.custom(viewHolder.icon.context, R.string.addedToFavs,R.drawable.ic_star_full,R.color.blue_700,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true, true).show()
            }else{
                Toasty.custom(viewHolder.icon.context, R.string.alreadyAdded, R.drawable.ic_attention,R.color.blue_700,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true, true).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(item: String, definition: String, currentItem: Item)
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val results = FilterResults()

                if (constraint==null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                    results.values = itemsFull
                    results.count = itemsFull.size
                } else {
                    val filteredItems = ArrayList<Item>()
                    for (row in itemsFull) {
                        if (row.itemName.lowercase()
                                .startsWith(constraint.toString().lowercase().trim())
                        ) {
                            filteredItems.add(row)
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = filteredItems 
                    results.count = filteredItems.size
                }

                return results
            }

            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                items.clear()
                items.addAll(results?.values as ArrayList<Item>)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The layout containing the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SearchFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@color/blue_700"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_linear">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_17sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_17sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_17sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_17sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/alphabet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_letter"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/searchCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchLinear">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/searchRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is how I use the adapter in my Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val searchView = activity?.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.searchView)
        searchView?.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                (mAdapter2 as RecyclerViewAdapter).filter.filter(newText)
                return false
            }
        })        

        mRecyclerView2 = binding.searchRecyclerView
        mRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView2.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        mLayoutManager2 = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        mAdapter2 = RecyclerViewAdapter(Constants.wordList as ArrayList<Item>, this)

        mRecyclerView2.layoutManager = mLayoutManager2
        mRecyclerView2.adapter = mAdapter2
    }
```

My `onItemClick` method:

```
override fun onItemClick(item: String, definition: String, currentItem: Item) {
                    val args = Bundle()
                    args.putString("Item", item)
                    args.putString("Definition", definition)

                    val inflatedFragment = InflatedItemFragment()
                    inflatedFragment.arguments = args
                    val fm = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager

                    inflatedFragment.show(fm, "inflatedItem")
                }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I edited the `publishResults` like so:

```
override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) { 
        items.clear() 
        items.addAll(results?.values as ArrayList<Item>) 
        notifyDataSetChanged() 
    }
```

Now when I click on the empty area I get an error:

```
2021-08-28 13:23:19.220 8125-8125/com.jpdevzone.knowyourwords
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jpdevzone.knowyourwords, PID: 8125
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.jpdevzone.knowyourwords.adapters.RecyclerViewAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(RecyclerViewAdapter.kt:29)
```

and its pointing to this line inside the onClick method:

```
val currentItem = items[position]
```

Comment: Add the whole adapter code with question. Also the layout

Comment: @ADM Just edited my post. Not sure which layout I should provide, so I added the one containing the RecyclerView. Hope it if of use.

Comment: This is Weird . can u pls Add the code where you are using the `RecyclerViewAdapter` . I can not see any issue with `RecyclerViewAdapter` except one i.e reference of `tempItems` items are same . and that should not be an issue i guess . add the code it will help in finding the actual problem .

Comment: Also confirm one thing since you are using Fragment. it might be possible the you have a fragment below this one and the below one is getting the click . That might be an issue . Check this one and let me know.

Comment: @ADM Hi, there is no other fragment below. Please check the updates in my post. Thank you!

Comment: @ADM Basicaly the first few positions of the `items` arraylist are triggering the click, even though they are filtered and invisible to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Adding `notifyItemRangeChanged(0,items.size)` to `publishResults` inside `getFilter()` solved the problem.

```
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
    items.clear()
    items.addAll(results?.values as ArrayList<Item>)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,items.size)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```